# Menu : Handling click events : DIalogBox

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

I did red [LINK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) [LINK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html)

I wrote this in main activity

```
@Override   
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.infos:
            infos();
            return true;
        case R.id.waring:
            waring();
            return true;
        case R.id.credits:
            credits();
            return true;
        case R.id.about:
            about();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
private void about() {
//      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      // custom dialog

}
```

Where should I put my alertbox ?

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("About").setMessage("el viva Stackoverflow           !").create();
```

in 
    private void about() 
or directly

in 
    case R.id.about:
                about();

Is the alertbox syntax correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly place the code in swith case instead of have new method(about). Just check whehter you have imported properly or not.
You ca import all the imports by simply pressing ctrl+shift+O.

You can use the sample code below to create the alertdiaolg .

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
       .setCancelable(false)
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Where should I put my alertbox ?

It does not matter, basically you'll get more compact code if you avoid one-line functions or functions which are called from a single place only.

> Is the alertbox syntax correct ?

You should not forget to call `.show()` after `create()`, like this:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("About").setMessage("el viva Stackoverflow!").create().show();
```